# MXL USB Mic on an iPad 2?

Tags: audio, music, usb, hardware-recommendation, ipad

I am considering getting an iPad 2 because of the support for inputting an electric guitar in via an [Apogee JAM device](http://www.apogeedigital.com/products/jam.php). However, part of my bigger picture is to take an MXL .009 [USB Condensor Mic](http://www.mxlmics.com/products/USB/USB_009/USB_009.html) into the Garageband app. But I just read that the iPad 2 does not have a USB port on it.

Is there a way to take the audio from a MXL .009 USB mic into the iPad 2 similar to the way the Apogee jam works via the dock connection?

Answer (score 1):

My concern would be if the MXL USB mic expects to draw electrical power through the USB port. In that case the iPad 2 and the iPad Camera Connector Kit certainly would not provide enough power for the microphone. You should go to the MXL web site and check their support information.

The [Alesis IO Dock Pro](http://www.alesis.com/iodock), US$200.00, provides professional-quality audio and MIDI interfaces to the iPad 2, but only interfaces MIDI over USB, not audio over USB like with the MXL microphone you describe. The Alesis is designed to work with conventional condenser microphones with an XLR audio cable, and it provides phantom power.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Wheat Williams, the iPad 2 does not allow much power through the USB port found on iPad Camera Connector Kit (the first iPad had different specs), and even most thumb Flash drives require too much power. A work around that might suit under some recording circumstances is to use an AC powered USB hub, and let the MXL USB mic draw its power from the wall rather than straight from the iPad 2. The requirement of access to an AC source is the obvious drawback, but it does work well. Here's [a link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azjhW9hsQBw) to a video about the various uses for iPad Camera Connector Kit. (I did not do the video.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I can use an [ipad camera connector kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003K1EYM6) as shown in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbNu6nlywCo).